# Entity Framework: retrieve row that is not in a Date range

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have this query:

```
var query = _repository.GetAllIncluding(x => x.ContractRow, x => x.ContractRow.Contract)
                       .Where(x => (int)x.ContractRow.PeriodicityType == (int)CommonConsts.PeriodicityType.Yearly && 
                                   x.ContractRow.Contract.Date.AddYears(-(x.ContractRow.Period.Value / 2)) > x.DueDate
                                   || x.ContractRow.Contract.Date.AddYears(x.ContractRow.Period.Value / 2) < x.DueDate);
```

Where:

- `ContractRow.Contract.IssueDate` is of type `DateTime`
- `ContractRow.Period` is of type `short?`
- `DueDate` is of type `DateTime`

These types can't be changed.

The problem is in the `AddYears()` function.

If I use `.AddYears(-(2 / 2))` it returns the value I expect, but if I use `.AddYears(-(x.ContractRow.Period.Value / 2))`, where `ContractRow.Period` is `2` it shows a different result. Why?

Comment: Could it be because `-(2/2)` is rather different from `2/2` ? Also: you are using `AddYears()` in two places, please be totally clear about which one you are talking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, given that you are using DateTime.AddYears in your expression, that shouts that your repository method is returning `IEnumerable<Entity>` not `IQueryable<Entity>` and is executing the EF Linq query with `.ToList()`.  To save you a lot of pain in the future when your database gets big, or you try a similar pattern in a larger project, you really want to avoid this. The problem with this approach is that EF is retrieving *all* entities with their associated ContractRow and Contract records before you even touch on a `Where` clause. Against a data table of any significant size with any significant number of concurrent requests, this will absolutely kill your system.

For repository patterns I recommend returning `IQueryable<Entity>` and avoiding calls like `ToList` until they are absolutely needed.  So a GetAll method would look something like:

```
public IQueryable<Row> GetAll()
{
   var query = _context.Rows.AsQueryable();
   return query;
}
```

Note that we do not need to bother with `Include()` statements etc. Linq queries can happily reference related entities as part of the expression and EF will resolve these automatically. Projecting results using `Select()` will also resolve related entities. The only time you need `Include()` is where you specifically want to load and work with the entire entity structure. Typically this would just be Update scenarios. In that case you can add `.Include()` statements in the query after calling the repository method, you don't need to pass expressions to the method. It also gives you the flexibility to perform `.Count()`, `.Any()`, and pagination with `.OrderBy().Skip(n).Take(m)`, etc. (quite simple and flexible)

As for the repository method, the above is a simple example with no base criteria. Repositories provide a good separation point for testing, but also a good base point for common, global rules such as with Soft Delete (IsActive) restrictions, and Authentication/Authorization checks. For instance if you have a soft-delete system and default to active records:

```
public IQueryable<Row> GetAll(bool includeInactive = false)
{
   var query = includeInactive 
      ? _context.Rows.AsQueryable()
      : _context.Rows.Where(x => x.IsActive);
   return query;
}
```

Where most entities don't need an includeInactive option they just return the `Where(x => x.IsActive)`

This will help address future performance issues, but now raises a problem you may have seen, `AddYears` can't be used inside an EF Linq expression. This is because EF is trying to translate your expression down into SQL, and SQL doesn't understand `.AddYears`. Fortunately EF has support for dealing with this: `EntityFunctions`

With an `IQueryable<T>` repository method and `EntityFunctions.AddYears` you would have:

```
var query = _repository.GetAll()
    .Where(x => (int)x.ContractRow.PeriodicityType == (int)CommonConsts.PeriodicityType.Yearly 
        && (EntityFunctions.AddYears(x.ContractRow.Contract.Date, (x.ContractRow.Period.Value/-2)) > x.DueDate
            || EntityFunctions.AddYears(x.ContractRow.Contract.Date, x.ContractRow.Period.Value / 2)) < x.DueDate));
```

And lastly, the probable cause of your grief:  Operations, mixing AND and ORs... (You might have spotted it in the example above)

```
criteria = A AND B OR C
vs.
criteria = A AND (B OR C)
```

will produce different results. You need parenthesis around your date range check because without them, you get:

```
WHERE PeriodicType = Yearly AND Date > 2 years ago
   OR Date < 2 years from future (and PeriodicType can be anything it wants)

A AND B OR C == (A AND B) OR C
you want 
A AND (B OR C)
```

I might have started with that as the solution, but I really wanted to hopefully get across the potential performance pain point first. ;)